# Can we setup cpu memory requirement with python virtualenv

Tags: python, memory-management, cpu-usage, diskspace

As per definition virtualenv is a tool to create isolated Python environments. virtualenv creates a folder which contains all the necessary executables to use the packages that a Python project would need.

Is there way to created environment which can have restriction on resources CPU, Memory and Diskusage?

Answer (score 4):

No, virtual environments are a solution to manage Python library paths. It is not a virtualization system and does not enforce any restrictions on the process.